# AngularJS filter nested array and return parent object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, filter

I've recently started fiddling around with AngularJS. I'm making checkbox filters for my wine store.
An item looks like this:

```
        {
     "id": 17,
     "name": "Ermelinda Freitas Reserva",
     "tag_ids": [40, 12, 56, 6, 60],
     "tag_names": ["Roasted", "Robust", "Blackberry", "Mouth-filling", "Animal"],
     "price": 29,
     "weight": "0",
     "image": "1467208469_wijn1.jpg",
     "stock": 57,
     "year": 1998,
     "special": 0,
     "color_id": 1,
     "color": "Red",
     "region_id": 25,
     "region": "Alentejo",
     "country_id": 6,
     "country": "Portugal",
     "grape_ids": [34, 35, 20],
     "grape_names": ["Castelão", "Touriga Naçional", "Cabernet Sauvignon"]
 }
```

I've manage to make filters for countries and other non-array properties of the item like this:

```
for(i = 0; i< wines.length; i++){

      if($scope.countries.indexOf(wines[i].country) === -1) $scope.countries.push(wines[i].country);
    };
```

But now i'm trying to make one for the grapes. I started off by collecting all unique values in an array as such:

```
angular.forEach($scope.wines, function(wine){
  angular.forEach(wine.grape_names, function(grape){
    for(i = 0; i< wine.grape_names.length; i++){
      if($scope.grapes.indexOf(wine.grape_names[i]) === -1) $scope.grapes.push(wine.grape_names[i]);
    };
  });
})
```

So now I need to check if an item has any grapes that match the selected filter and here is where I am stuck:

```
$scope.filter.grape = {};
$scope.filterByGrape = function(wine){

  angular.forEach(wine.grape_names, function(grape){

    return $scope.filter.grape[grape] || noFilter($scope.filter.grape);
  })
};
```

The filters :

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 " data-id="{{wine.id}}" ng-init="getQuantity(wine.id)" data-ng-repeat="wine in filteredWines =(wines | orderBy:defaultOrder | filter:filterByColor | filter:filterByCountry | filter:filterByGrape | priceRangeFilter:priceRangeSlider | yearRangeFilter:yearRangeSlider | filter:search) | start: (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage | limitTo:itemsPerPage">
```

[image]

All help is very welcome !

Comment: Do you need to do it only with javascript or could you use libraries like underscore or lodash?

Comment: I've never heard of these things :)

Comment: I would avoid using that many filters, if your data is large enough performance is going to be a problem, it would be much easier and performing to manage it in the controller. Are the filter and results in the same controller?

Comment: https://lodash.com/ Is a utility library with quite a few nice functions available that fit your requirements very well

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Everything is done within a single controller. How do you suggest reducing the amount of filters ? I'm still trying to figure out the best way to split up my code into services/factories/filters/directories. I will take a look at Iodash

Comment: So, assuming you have wines in your scope (with all your wines), add a new property filteredWines (that would be the one used in your ng-repeat).
Now, when filter needs to be applied, you call a function in your controller that refreshed this filteredWines property (so updates the list).
Problem with filters are that they are executed in every digest cycle (and there are lots of them), so as soon as your list of wines was large enough, the whole application would become slow.

Comment: Something like this ?$scope.$watch('search', function (query) {

      $scope.filteredWines = filterFilter($scope.wines, query);
      $scope.totalItems = $scope.filteredWines.length;
      $scope.itemsPerPage = parseInt($scope.defaultLimit);
      $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.totalItems / $scope.itemsPerPage);
      $scope.currentPage = 1;
    });

Comment: But instead of $scope.filteredWines i should be using $scope.wines.filtered or something ?

Comment: You shouldn't need a watch here, if you are binding search field using ng-model, you can use ng-change (and using ng-model-options define a debounce time) to call a function that builds the list, but yes it is the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are only checking the first iteration of the forEach for grape_names, you return from the function there.

```
$scope.filter.grape = {};
$scope.filterByGrape = function(wine){
  var found = noFilter($scope.filter.grape);
  angular.forEach(wine.grape_names, function(grape){
     found = $scope.filter.grape[grape] || found;
  })
  return found;
};
```

Comment: I've manage to make it work like this. However, the filter is reversed so I get no results unless i manually check every box. Also, some checkboxes don't return any items...    $scope.filter.grape = {};
    var found = {};
    $scope.filterByGrape = function(wine){

      angular.forEach(wine.grape_names, function(grape_name){

        angular.forEach($scope.grapes, function(grape){
          if(grape_name == grape){
            found = $scope.filter.grape[grape];
          }
        })
      })
      return found;
    };